# Is there a simple way to create an object of an inner class in Android?

Tags: java, android

I put some utility function and class in a PublicParFun, if I hope to create a object of OnlyFolderFilter .

I have to write the code `new PublicParFun().new OnlyFolderFilter`, is there a simple way to create an object of an inner class in Android?

```
public class PublicParFun {

    public static void ClearIcon(Context myContext) {
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)myContext.getSystemService(android.content.Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.cancel(myContext.getResources().getInteger(R.integer.NotificationID));
    }

    public class OnlyFileFilter implements FilenameFilter{
        boolean isExcludeHidden;

        public OnlyFileFilter(boolean isExcludeHidden){
            this.isExcludeHidden=isExcludeHidden;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
            File f=new File(dir, name);

            if (isExcludeHidden) {
                return f.isFile() && (f.isHidden() == false);
            }else{
                return f.isFile();
            }
        }
    }


    public class OnlyFolderFilter implements FilenameFilter{
        boolean isExcludeHidden;

        public OnlyFolderFilter(boolean isExcludeHidden){
            this.isExcludeHidden=isExcludeHidden;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
            File f=new File(dir, name);

            if (isExcludeHidden) {
                return f.isDirectory() && (f.isHidden() == false);
            }else{
                return f.isDirectory();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Make `OnlyFileFilter` a `static class` then just call `new PublicParFun.OnlyFileFilter(...)`

Comment: Thanks！ But static class is not good way because there are many limitation about static class

Comment: "there are many limitation about static class" What makes you think that? If a nested class doesn't rely on any instance fields or methods from the wrapping class it really should be static. [Read up](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [flkes already said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38755836/is-there-a-simple-way-to-create-an-object-of-an-inner-class-in-android#comment64885392_38755836), a good solution is to convert your inner classes to static inner classes.

- A normal inner class cannot exist without the instance of its outer class and therefore you need to call `new PublicParFun().new OnlyFolderFilter()`, effectively creating two objects instead of one.
- When using static inner classes you effectively state that the inner class does not need a instance of the outer class (and its fields) and can exist for itself.

You are not using the fields of the outer class which makes your inner classes perfect candidates for static inner classes.
The difference between the two types is not only the instantiation code:

- With your "double-constructor" you create two objects every time you want a new inner class.
- The instance of a normal inner class holds a reference on its outer object, so keep the outer object alive as long as you have a reference to the inner object.
- An additional point is readability. When reading the code you can immediately tell that the inner class is not modifying or reading the state of an instance of the outer class if the static keyword is applied.